# PHP - Workaround for reading user-selected text from PDF?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

I am working on a project that allows a user to upload text or content from an HTML page in Japanese and then use their cursor to select words in the text/content to translate into English. However, I would like to be able to expand this functionality to PDF files. Essentially, I'd like the user to be able to submit a PDF file and have the browser render that PDF file in such a way that when the user selects/highlights words in the PDF, the browser can somehow relay what the text of the highlighted section is, such as via javascript, to be then relayed to a PHP variable.

I know there are a lot of posts on stackoverflow asking similar questions (I've spent hours upon hours trying to sort through them all!), but I can't seem to find a definitive answer on whether this is possible. It seems there are lots of options for converting PDF to HTML or extracting text from PDF, but to be quite honest, I'm confused if any of those options are relevant to what I am trying to accomplish. And I know there's a javascript API for Adobe, but I'm under the impression the javascript needs to be embedded in the PDF already, which will not be true if the user is uploading their own PDF files to render. Even if that is possible, it seems there's no native text selection support in the Adobe javascript API....

Is there a straightforward workaround (oxymoron?) to doing this? Again, I want to be able to pass text selected in a PDF to a variable -- the effect is the user highlights words they don't know so those words can be added to a word bank for retrieval in a dictionary.

Let me know if I can be clearer on anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to convert the PDF to HTML (see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20convert%20pdf%20to%20html)) and then you are already set as you already implemented everything for regular HTML.

Comment: Yea, that probably is the ideal solution here. However, the problem I seem to have then is finding a library that can handle Japanese fonts during the conversion without jumbling it all up into garbage. Is there a solution for that, or am I ultimately restricted for the time being to having just the ability to convert English PDF texts to HTML?

Comment: I dunno, it's been a while since I was doing conversion from PDF, and even then I didn't deal with Japanese. But if I had to guess you are missing one of the following: the conversion library does not support UTF8 or you don't have fonts that can display Japanese installed.

Comment: Hmmm, yea. I think the problem I keep running into is the native support for the UTF8 itself. Maybe this isn't feasible...I'll have to find a different way of thinking about the task, it seems...